# adding percent calculation to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a table with frequency counts and percentages. I have the frequency counts and calculated the percentages. When I try to add it to the dataframe, it's doesn't add the calculations to the dataframe. The code:

```
fpanel <- rename(count(surveydata, panel), Freq = n)
fpanel$proportion <- fpanel$Freq / dim(surveydata)[1]
fresponder <- rename(count(surveydata, panel, responder), Freq = n)
fresponder$percent <- c(fresponder[1,3] / fpanel[1,2], 
                        fresponder[2,3] / fpanel[1,2],
                        fresponder[3,3] / fpanel[2,2],
                        fresponder[4,3] / fpanel[2,2],
                        fresponder[5,3] / fpanel[3,2],
                        fresponder[6,3] / fpanel[3,2],
                        fresponder[7,3] / fpanel[4,2],
                        fresponder[8,3] / fpanel[4,2])
```

And the results:

[image]

The calculations are correct without adding to the dataframe but when I add it, I get "<dbl [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRZnL.png)>". What kind of error is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's not an error. You've created a column that's a list of numeric vectors of length 1. I'm not sure why you're calculating percentages this way—why not just divide frequencies by their grouped sums, or whatever the calculation is you're trying to do?

Comment: It's a list of doubles. You can see the values if you wrap the data in a data frame like this `data.frame(...)`. Avoid the list by reducing the result of your calculation to one value at a time.

Comment: FYI, I cringe whenever I see calculations being done using `[i,j]` notation. It seems highly likely that there is a far better (more resilient/robust) way to do this, whether by grouping/aggregate, joining, reshaping/pivoting, who knows. It would really help to have sample data to work with to improve the *process* and not just guess at resolving the *symptom*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fresponder` (and `fpanel`) is a `tibble`, and unlike `data.frame`s from which they inherit, `fresponder[1,2]` is *still a tibble*. As a hasty demonstration, `as.data.frame(fresponder)[1,2]` should return a `numeric` instead of a `tibble`.

```r
class(mtcars)
# [1] "data.frame"
mtcars[1,2]
# [1] 6
tibble(mtcars)[1,2]
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#     cyl
#   <dbl>
# 1     6
```

Untested, but try this:

```r
fr <- as.data.frame(fresponder)
fp <- as.data.frame(fpanel)
fresponder$percent <- c(fr[1,3] / fp[1,2], 
                        fr[2,3] / fp[1,2],
                        fr[3,3] / fp[2,2],
                        fr[4,3] / fp[2,2],
                        fr[5,3] / fp[3,2],
                        fr[6,3] / fp[3,2],
                        fr[7,3] / fp[4,2],
                        fr[8,3] / fp[4,2])
# rm(fp,fr)
```

(But ultimately, calculating `$percent` here in this way seems very fragile and not resilient/robust.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. As for the "fragility", it's a quick, dirty solution. Not something I'm going to be using repeatedly. It works for this particular case. Also learned to mind my tibbles!